# Sphinx / ReadTheDocs still tries to build a module when I try to mock it

Tags: mocking, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I am attempting to build documentation using Sphinx on ReadTheDocs, for [a project](https://readthedocs.org/projects/catalyst-cooperative-pudl/) that depends on a bunch of pydata packages, some of which depend on C libraries which are not available on ReadTheDocs (namely the `python-snappy` package, which provides the `snappy` module, implementing Google's snappy compression algorithm, which we are using in Apache Parquet files).

The documentation [suggests that the solution](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules) is to mock those python modules so that `autodoc` can import them, even if the code isn't really there, using the `autodoc_mock_imports` parameter in `conf.py` So I've got

```py
autodoc_mock_imports = ['snappy', 'python-snappy']
```

in my Sphinx `conf.py` (I think it's really supposed to be just `snappy` in there, but I wasn't 100% sure and it wasn't working with `snappy` at first, so I added the package name as well as the module name... and it still didn't work).

However, the documentation build is still attempting to compile `snappy` and predictably failing, because the C-language headers aren't available. When the build is collecting requirements, it finds `python-snappy`, I think in the project `setup.py` and says:

```
Collecting python-snappy (from pudl==0.1.dev398+g5e075d4)
```

And subsequently the build fails:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pudl, python-snappy
  Building wheel for pudl (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pudl (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/catalyst-cooperative-pudl/.cache/pip/wheels/a4/5f/b6/1f8213aeb5876af1c140b54dce3466b845d989ca1101da875a
  Building wheel for python-snappy (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for python-snappy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Complete output from command /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/catalyst-cooperative-pudl/envs/python-packaging/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z6c1cop3/python-snappy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-r54uwk2d --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  copying snappy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  copying snappy/snappy_cffi_builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  copying snappy/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  copying snappy/hadoop_snappy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  copying snappy/snappy_formats.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  copying snappy/snappy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  copying snappy/snappy_cffi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  running build_ext
  building 'snappy._snappy' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/include/python3.7m -c snappy/snappymodule.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/snappy/snappymodule.o
  snappy/snappymodule.cc:31:10: fatal error: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory
   #include <snappy-c.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-snappy
  Running setup.py clean for python-snappy
Successfully built pudl
Failed to build python-snappy
```

`python-snappy` is commented out of the `requirements.txt` that is included in the documentation build, but of course it is still included in the project `setup.py` in the `install_requires` parameter.

Why is the mocking not working? How do I get it to stop trying to build this package that can't succeed? On my local system (which has the ``libsnappy-dev` package installed) the documentation build seems to work fine.

The full output from the failed build can be found here:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/catalyst-cooperative-pudl/builds/9376117/

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that I had also explicitly told Read The Docs to build and install my `pudl` package using `pip`, in the `.readthedocs.yml` configuration file:

```
# Set the version of Python and requirements required to build your docs
python:
  version: 3.7
  install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
    - method: pip
      path: .
  system_packages: true
```

Which meant that it was trying to create a `pudl` distribution, by running the `setup.py` found in the top level of the repository, which predictably failed due to the lack of the `snappy` C headers.

The solution was to conditionally exclude the `python-snappy` package from the `install_requires` parameter in `setup.py` based on the `READTHEDOCS` environment variable, leaving the dependency to be satisfied by the mocked module as specified by `autodoc_mock_imports` in `conf.py`:

```py
install_requires = [
    'coloredlogs',
    'datapackage',
    'dbfread',
    'goodtables',
    'jupyter',
    'jupyterlab',
    'matplotlib',
    'nbval',
    'networkx>=2.2',
    'numpy',
    'pandas>=0.24',
    'psycopg2',
    'pyarrow>=0.14.0',
    'pyyaml',
    'scikit-learn>=0.20',
    'scipy',
    'sqlalchemy>=1.3',
    'sqlalchemy-postgres-copy',
    'tableschema',
    'timezonefinder',
    'xlsxwriter',
]

# We are installing the PUDL module to build the docs, but the C libraries
# required to build snappy aren't available on RTD, so we need to exclude it
# from the installed dependencies here, and mock it for import in docs/conf.py
# using the autodoc_mock_imports parameter:
if not os.getenv('READTHEDOCS'):
    install_requires.append('python-snappy')
```

Another potential solution would be to add the `pudl` package directory to `sys.path` in the `conf.py` so that the package is importable, even though it's not installed.  However, I am using `setuptools_scm` to automatically generate a version number for use by the packaging and documentation, and for that to work the `pudl` package needs to actually be built as a distribution and installed.